# sdl2 setup with Visual Studio 2010 Express C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sdl

I am trying to setup sdl2 with vs 2010 express c++.
 I followed lazy foos tutorials, added include and lib to vc++ directories, SDL2.lib and SDLmain.lib to linker->input
 and changed subsystem to windows.

But I am getting error it says;

*Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or
 enter code here directory  c:\sdl2-2.0.0\include\sdl_stdinc.h*

I have visual studio 2010 c++ redistributable installed. Anyone has suggestions ?

Comment: Can you post a link to an image showing your include and library directories as well as additional dependencies?

Comment: include and lib directories : http://imgur.com/oVcJ5Yu                   additional dependencies : http://imgur.com/oVcJ5Yu

Comment: Hi, both links were the same but from what I can see I think the issue is with the include and lib paths. Comparing with the Lazyfoo tutorial it can be seen that you appear to missing key directories ($(VCInstallDir)include etc). Could you try adding the missing entires so that it matches the tutorials

Comment: Sorry for wrong link. additional dependencies are here : http://imgur.com/BNVdniW. I am adding directories now.

Comment: include directories : $(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;C:\SDL2-2.0.0\include                  lib directories : $(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib;C:\SDL2-2.0.0\lib\x86;                            but still not working. I think i have a problem with installation of vc++ 2010. I created win32 project. It gives another error  :         error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory.

Comment: Hi, yes I would say this is definitely a VC issue. Quickest thing to do would be a clean install of it and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna try it